# Utilizing private methods/vars inside module

Tags: 7

I'm creating a custom module which uses a few hooks and then after the form is submitted it will dive into custom PHP interaction that interfaces with an external restful API.

I want some of these variables and functions to be private as they will contain business rules and some variables that I wouldn't want someone to get their hands on (easily).

I'm uncertain of how to do this in Drupal. I understand that I would need to create a PHP class which would then have private/public methods available inside of it. But how do I do this?

Do I build this PHP class in its own file outside of my .module file and then use `files[] = includes/MyClass.class.php` in my .info file to import this external class file in?

Then once it's successfully imported in I could instantiate it with `$something = new MyClass();`?

Is it that simple to do, or is there another/better way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - it's that simple. Remember; Drupal is only PHP.

Although your class should be called `MyClass.php` rather than `MyClass.class.php` to adhere to the [Drupal Coding Standards for OO code](https://www.drupal.org/node/608152#naming) (note - this isn't explicitly declared, but is hinted at when they describe the Interface file naming conventions).

Just to pad this out a bit; you could also use the [X Autoload](https://www.drupal.org/project/xautoload) module to allow for PSR-4 style autoloading instead of adding your class in the `files[]` array. I do this for as much D7 code as possible now (where I'm not using Composer Manager), and would whole heartedly recommend it.

> xautoload is a comprehensive and yet highly efficient PHP class
>   loading suite.
>
> Most importantly, it provides Drupal-8-style PSR-4 (and the old D8
>   PSR-0-style in "lib") autoloading for Drupal 7. But it is also a great
>   tool for 3rd party autoloading.

Comment: Good catch! So how exactly does X Autoload work if I were to install it? @Chapabu

Comment: That isn't a discussion for comments or as an addendum to a different question @Exziled - if you have specific questions about xautoload after you've read the module page/documentation and installed/used it, please ask them as separate questions